# Multer remove file if not uploaded completly

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, multer

I am using Multer for File upload with node JS. But if i abbort the upload there is still a file left with a random name and without extension. My question is how to delete the file if it wasnt uploaded completly?

Answer (score 0):

You should not upload file before submitting form. So you should add upload trigger button to forms submitting button. In this case file will not be uploaded at all. If you provide more information maybe I can suggest something more precise.

Comment: the deal is, i have a form that i submit. The browser is uploading the file after you click submit via simple multipart request. The problem is if you press esc and stop the upload, you are left with X% that were already uploaded.